# Why is renderInContext so much slower than drawing to the screen?

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer

I have a pretty large `CAShapeLayer` that I'm rendering. The layer is completely static, but it's contained in a `UIScrollView` so it can move around and be zoomed -- basically, it must be redrawn every now and then. In an attempt to improve the framerate of this scrolling, I set `shouldRasterize = YES` on the layer, which worked perfectly. Because I never change any property of the layer it never has a rasterization miss and I get a solid 60 fps. High fives all around, right?

Until the layer gets a little bigger. Eventually -- and it doesn't take long -- the rasterized image gets too large for the GPU to handle. According to my console, `<Notice>: CoreAnimation: surface 2560 x 4288 is too large`, and it just doesn't draw anything on the screen. I don't really blame it -- `2560 x 4288` is pretty big -- but I spent a while scratching my head before I noticed this in the device console.

Now, my question is: how can I work around this limitation? How can I rasterize a really large layer?

The obvious solution seems to be to break the layer up into multiple sublayers, say one for each quadrant, and rasterize each one independently. Is there an "easy" way to do this? Can I create a new layer that renders a rectangular area from another layer? Or is there some other solution I should explore?

### Edit

Creating a tiled composite seems to have really bad performance because the layers are re-rasterized every time they enter the screen, creating for a very jerky scrolling experience. Is there some way to cache those rasterizations? Or is this the wrong approach altogether?

### Edit

Alright, here's my current solution: render the layer once to a `CGImageRef`. Create multiple tile layers using sub-rectangles from that image, and actually put those on the screen.

```
- (CALayer *)getTiledLayerFromLayer:(CALayer *)sourceLayer withHorizontalTiles:(int)horizontalTiles verticalTiles:(int)verticalTiles
{
    CALayer *containerLayer = [CALayer layer];
    CGFloat tileWidth = sourceLayer.bounds.size.width / horizontalTiles;
    CGFloat tileHeight = sourceLayer.bounds.size.height / verticalTiles;

    // make sure these are integral, otherwise you'll have image alignment issues!
    NSLog(@"tileWidth:%f height:%f", tileWidth, tileHeight);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sourceLayer.bounds.size, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef tileContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [sourceLayer renderInContext:tileContext];
    CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(tileContext);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    for(int horizontalIndex = 0; horizontalIndex < horizontalTiles; horizontalIndex++) {
        for(int verticalIndex = 0; verticalIndex < verticalTiles; verticalIndex++) {
            CGRect frame = CGRectMake(horizontalIndex * tileWidth, verticalIndex * tileHeight, tileWidth, tileHeight);
            CGRect visibleRect = CGRectMake(horizontalIndex / (CGFloat)horizontalTiles, verticalIndex / (CGFloat)verticalTiles, 1.0f / horizontalTiles, 1.0f / verticalTiles);
            CALayer *tile = [CALayer layer];
            tile.frame = frame;
            tile.contents = (__bridge id)image;
            tile.contentsRect = visibleRect;
            [containerLayer addSublayer:tile];
        }
    }

    CGImageRelease(image);

    return containerLayer;
}
```

This works great...sort of. One the one hand, I get 60fps panning and zooming of a `1980 x 3330` layer on a retina iPad. On the other hand, it takes 20 seconds to start up! So while this solution solves my original problem, it gives me a new one: how can I generate the tiles faster?

Literally all of the time is spent in the `[sourceLayer renderInContext:tileContext];` call. This seems weird to me, because if I just add that layer directly I can render it about 40 times per second, according to the Core Animation Instrument. Is it possible that creating my own image context causes it to not use the GPU or something?

Answer (score 2):

Breaking the layer into tiles is the only solution. You can however implement it in many different ways. I suggest doing it manually (creating layers & sublayers on your own), but many recommend using CATiledLayer http://www.mlsite.net/blog/?p=1857, which is the way maps are usually implemented - zooming and rotating is quite easy with this one. The tiles of CATiledLayer are loaded (drawn) *on demand*, just after they are put on the screen. This implies a short delay (blink) before the tile is fully drawn and AFAIK it is quite hard to get rid of this behaviour.

Comment: Don't use CATiledLayer. It is implemented very badly (iOS 5 + 6) and kills performance for all non-trivial cases. It seems to be a "proof of concept" from Apple rather than a class they expect people to actually use. The tiles are NOT loaded in a sane manner - instead they have a (badly designed) custom caching mechanism, and ... they ignore the hardware's own tile-based caching. Sigh

Comment: what do you suggest instead?

Comment: Write your own code. Apple currently - 2013 - does not provide any solution for these problems.